# the powershell replace command fails because the string contains the character '\' in it

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm pulling the locally signed on user of a machine from WMI, and storing it in a variable, like so:

```
$user = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $hostname).username
```

And that works great.  The problem is that WMI returns the information in the format

*contoso\username*

I need to plug the variable into the Get-ADUser command, which won't accept the

*"contoso\"*

When I try to use the replace command in powershell, it fails, due to the presence of the '\' in the command:

```
$user = $user -replace "CONTOSO\"

The regular expression pattern CONTOSO\ is not valid.
At line:1 char:1
+ $user = $user -replace "CONTOSO\"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CONTOSO\:String) [],        RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

Is there another method to remove those characters so I can plug it into Get-ADUser? Perhaps cleanup the output from *gwmi* before I plug it into Get-ADUser? Or, is there some sort of character escape sequence?

Comment: \ is an escape character in most languages that I know of. Try replacing it with \\: `$user = $user -replace "CONTOSO\\"`

Comment: Awesome sauce! That did it, and, duh! Should've thought to try that from the get-go.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `-replace` operator does regular expression replacements. In regular expressions the character `\` is a special character used for escaping special characters, so you need `\\` to match a literal backslash.